# Prove $f|_{U_0}$ is $m$-to-$1$ except at $z_0$.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

*Let $f$ be analytic on a domain $U$, $z_0\in U$, and $w_0=f(z_0)$. Suppose that $\mbox{ord}_{z_0}(f-w_0)=m\in\mathbb N$. Prove that there is an open set $U_0$ with $z_0\in U_0\subset U$ such that $f^{-1}(w_0)\cap U_0=\{z_0\}$ and $f^{-1}(w)\cap U_0$ contains exactly $m$ elements (without repetition) for $w\in f(U_0)\setminus\{w_0\}$. This means that $f|_{U_0}$ is $m$-to-$1$ except at $z_0$.*

---

**Proof**: First, since $\mbox{ord}_{z_0}(f-w_0)=m$, when writing $f-w_0$ as its Laurent series, then $a_m \ne 0$, and $a_n=0$ for all $n<m$ (this is the definition of $\mbox{ord}_{z_0}(f-w_0)=m$, which essentially says $m$ is the minimum power actually appearing in the Laurent series with a nonzero coefficient.) Then we can write
\begin{align*}
f(z)-w_0&=\sum_{n=m}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n \\
&=a_m(z-z_0)^m+a_{m+1}(z-z_0)^{m+1}+\cdots
\end{align*}
This also means $z_0$ is either a removable singularity or a pole of $f-w_0$. Since $m\in \mathbb{N}$, we know $z_0$ is removable and after removing the singularity, we say that $z_0$ is a zero of $f-w_0$ (of order $m$). Also, it means there exists a holomorphic function $g$ in the disk $D(z_0,r)$ with $g(z_0) \ne 0$ such that $f(z)-w_0=(z-z_0)^m g(z)$. Would this be correct so far?

We have just finished talking about the [Open Mapping Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)) and Inverse Mapping Theorem, so it's could be possible this question is an application of one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this claim is included in some proof of the open mapping theorem, for example, see W. Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*, Thm 10.23.

Your discussion is correct. Let's start from $f(z)-w_0=(z-z_0)^m g(z)$, where $g(z)$ is holomorphic in $D(z_0,r)$ and never vanishes.

**Claim:** There exists a holomorphic function $h(z)$, such that $g(z)=(h(z))^m$ in $D(z_0,r)$.
**Proof**: Consider $g'/g$ which is holomorphic in $D(z_0,r)$. Hence we can find some $G$ holomorphic in $D(z_0,r)$, such that $G'=g'/g$. Hence, we can choose one $G$ such that $\exp G=g$. Thus, $h(z)=G(z)/m$ is what we want.

Now we have $f(z)-w_0=((z-z_0)h(z))^m$. Choose a small neighborhood $V$ of $z_0$ such that $(z-z_0)h(z)$ is one-to-one in $V$, by the open mapping theorem, since the derivative of that is not zero at $z_0$. Now the conclusion follows from the fact that $z\mapsto z^m$ is $m$-to-$1$.

Comment: Eclipse, thank you for your answer! Are we choosing the open set $U_0$ to be the disc $V$ that we found?

Comment: @EthanAlvaree Yes, exactly.

Answer (score -1):

As you said, you can write $f(z)-f(c)=(z-c)^ng(z)$ where $g(c)\neq 0$ is holomorphic where $f$ is. Since $f$ is holomorphic, we can restrict ourselves to a nbhd $N$ where $f$ attains the value $f(c)$ only once, by the identity theorem.

Since $g(c)\neq 0$ there is a neighborhood $V\subseteq N$ of $c$ where $g$ is nonzero. In such neighborhood you can pick an $n$-th root $q$ of $g$; i.e. $q$ holomorphic with $q^n=g$.

If you let $h=(z-c)q$ then $f(z)-f(c)=q(z)^n$, and $h'(c)=q(c)$ and since $q(c)^n=g(c)\neq 0$; $h'(c)\neq 0$. This means there is further a nbhd $U$ where $h:U\to h(U)$ is *biholomorphic*, i.e. we have written $f(z)=f(c)+h(z)^n$ with $h$ biholomorphic, all this in $U$. Since $h(c)=0$, the open mapping theorem guarantees there is an open ball $B=B(0,r)$ inside $h(U)$. Let $W=h^{-1}(B)$, so that $\tilde h=r^{-1}h:W\to B(0,1)$. Note then that we can write $f$ has a series of compositions $t\circ p \circ \tilde h$ where $p(z)=z^n$ and $t(z)=r^nz+f(c)$.

The end result is we have factored $f$ into a biholomorphism $\tilde h:W\simeq B(0,1)$, a linear biholomorphism $t:B(0,1)\to B(f(c),r^n)$ and the usual $n$-fold cover of the unit disk (minus the origin!) by itself $z\mapsto z^n$.

This is known as the local normal form of a holomorphic mapping.